# How do I highlight a UILabel when the finger touches it during the tap motion?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a news feed, similar to Facebook's.  When a user taps on a name on Facebook's news feed, the name highlights with a grey background when the finger is down. When the finger is lifted, the highlight goes away.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

implement functions below in any subclass of UIResponder(such as in UIViewController)

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
```

judge if the touch is inside UILabel by touches[0].locationInView(yourUILabel)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[self imageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

And imageWithColor looks like this:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting a different approach which would work for your job. I'm suggesting that you simply add a button which has the width & height of the label and make it transparent. Then add your label as a subview on top of that. Using the button's tap events, you can change the color of the label thus highlighting it. See my example below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //have a property named label
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
    [_label setText:@"LABEL"];
    [_label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapDown) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapCancel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapCancel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    [button addSubview:_label];   
}

-(void)tapDown{
    _label.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
}

-(void)tapCancel{
    _label.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}
```